Is there a way to define Boundary_pT with a two-phase water?
I'm trying to study a two-phase flow problem where, at the source, I have a quantity x of the mass flow as vapor. From what I understand, the “fixed composition value” “X” can help define this, but in my code, if I apply 0.95 (95% of my flow as fluid), I get the following error:
The boundary mass fractions in the “WaterIF97” medium in the “boundary_pT” model do not add up to 1 : The sum of the mass fractions of the medium “WaterIF97” in the model “Boundary_pT” does not equal 1. Instead, sum(X_boundary) = 0.95: X_boundary[1] = 0.95 “water”
I tried looking for examples with the same question but couldn't find anything.
Is there a way to define such a boundary condition with steam and liquid water?

In Modelica.Fluid and Modelica.Medium the vector X represents the mass fraction of different constituents in a mixture fluid. The vapor fraction/steam quality of WaterIF97 is not represented by the vector X as the vapor/liquid is regarded as the same fluid (H20).
There is no way to directly specify the steam quality in a Boundary_pT. Instead, you must set the pressure and specific enthalpy that corresponds to your desired 95 % vapor fraction. If you use a MassFlowSource_h — in which the boundary pressure is calculated by the downstream hydraulic model — the prescribed specific enthalpy must be variable in order to maintain a constant vapor fraction during the simulation.
You could write your own function that calculates h as a function of (p,x) or (T,x) in the two-phase region. To my knowledge there is no such function in the WaterIF97 package.

Thanks for your reply, you're right about the IF97 water. As I'm a new user of this software, I adjusted my boundary conditions to evaporate the water in the strip source but I think we can only have 100% water or 100% vapor (phase 1 or 2). I'll see if I can readjust my model to get the specific result (5% / 95%). Do you think this is feasible? if so the x value is always equal to one wich means 100% of a substance

Not sure if I'm answering your question but (1) yes the mass fraction X[1] for water is always 1.0. It is not the same as the vapor fraction/steam quality x. (2) if you want to specify 95 % steam quality x you can use the definition that x = (h - h_liquid)/(h_vapor - h_liquid) and isolate h for the boundary component. h_liquid and h_vapor are the bubble and dew enthalpies which are returned from the functions bubbleEnthalpy() and dewEnthalpy() in the WaterIF97 package.
